# CSR Matrix Shape Is Not Like Expected

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to create a sparse matrix with ratings data. My ratings table include user_index (which unique for every user), product_index (which is also unique for every product) and score.

Ratings Table:

| user_index | product_index | rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 15 | 5 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 |
| .. | .. | .. |

Of course there are products which are rated by multiple customers and there are customers which rated multiple products.

What I'm doing is that create a sparse matrix rating table which is like:

| Product Index/User Index | 0 | 1 | 2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **0** | 1 | 5 | - | - |
| **1** | - | - | 1 | - |
| **...** | - | - | - | - |

So sparse matrix shape should be number of unique elements in product_index and user_index.

My creating sparse matrix code is:

```py
ratings_mat_coo = coo_matrix((ratings["rating"], (ratings["product_index"], ratings["user_index"])))
ratings_matrix = ratings_mat_coo.tocsr()
```

- ratings['rating'].size : **3733438**
- ratings['product_index'].unique().size : **101460**
- ratings['user_index'].unique().size : **228805**

Expected Shape : **(101460, 228805)**

ratings_matrix.shape : **(145807, 228805)**

I didn't get the problem. Why it's not like expected ?

Comment: what's the max product index?

Comment: The max item is 145806.

Comment: You have all-0 rows where there is no product index in your long dataframe. If you want to get rid of them, reencode the indices so there's no missing values and then build the sparse matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood the problem with hpaulj's question. I thought user_index max item equals to number of unique elements in list but it's not. So shape created according to max item. I've solved the problem with reordering user_index list.